# How to create a new ray with the help of a cycle and constantly change its direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a code -

```c#
Vector3 rayDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-Spread, Spread), Random.Range(-Spread, Spread), 0);
Ray ray = new Ray(BulletSpawn.position, BulletSpawn.forward + rayDirection);
RaycastHit raycastHit;
RaycastHit checkHit;
Distance = MaxDistance;
for(float distance = MaxDistance; distance > 0; distance -= 20)
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(BulletSpawn.transform.position, BulletSpawn.forward + rayDirection, out raycastHit, Distance))
    {
        PrintDecal(raycastHit);
        Distance -= 20;

        rayDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-WoodSpread, WoodSpread), Random.Range(-WoodSpread, WoodSpread), 0); 
        Ray checkRay = new Ray(raycastHit.point + ray.direction * 1.2F, -BulletSpawn.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(checkRay, out checkHit, 3))
        {
            PrintDecal(checkHit);
        }
    }       
}
```

Is it possible to do it was like in the -
[image]

That is, when hit, the next ray was created with a random direction from the point checkHit (point of departure of the conditional bullet). How this implement without creating five methods for each ray, but that all will be in one method be. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to do all of these in 1 object?  Or would having a ray object be allowed?

Comment: Sorry, but the second sentence I did not understand

Comment: @xomen, since Unity is a component based engine you can create a new GameObject to represent each ray.   I am basically asking if you want to create multiple objects to represent the path of the bullet?

Comment: @xomen or if you just want this to happen once? (But go through walls for its distance)

Comment: @Eddge Is it possible with the creation of new objects, if it is a good option (in this version, the performance will not suffer?). The main thing is that to each next ray there were conditional parameters (speed, distance). You are hinting that when the first hit, the prefab of the next ray was created and data on the past was transmitted to it ?(I do not know how to pass parameters to the new prefab)

Comment: You could put the code in a function and on each ray hit, recursively call the function passing the hit coordinates as parameters for the new ray. The first call would happen with ray spawn as the coordinates of course.